# Adding exception to reverse proxy in Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have configured an application (jitsi-meet) on an ubuntu 16.04 server machine, being served through Apache. The DocumentRoot of the application is at /usr/share/jitsi-meet and the Apache configuration has been taken care by the automatic installation of the application through a script. The server has a FQDN and the application is available directly through the base url, say, http://example.com. I also installed an SSL certificate through letsencrypt which also took care of the http to https redirection.

The current Apache configuration available at /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf [looks like this.](https://pastebin.com/NQFrQsep)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName example.com

  SSLProtocol TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH$
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"

  DocumentRoot "/usr/share/jitsi-meet"
  <Directory "/usr/share/jitsi-meet">
    Options Indexes MultiViews Includes FollowSymLinks
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

      ErrorDocument 404 /static/404.html

Alias "/config.js" "/etc/jitsi/meet/example.com-config.js"
  <Location /config.js>
    Require all granted
  </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /http-bind http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://localhost:5280/http-bind/

    ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /forum http://192.168.1.5/forum
ProxyPassReverse /forum http://192.168.1.5/forum

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.html
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/full$
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/pri$
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to add an exception to the reverseproxy configuration of my Apache so that http://example.com/forum redirects to another website that is hosted on another machine in the same network, say, http://192.168.1.5/forum. (edited to add the info in configuration-not working)

Apache configuration is not my forte so you'll have to be gentle with me. I tried simply changing the part where the reverse proxy for /http-bind is set up, by redirecting it to my forum url and it kind-of works (no scripts running) so it gives me hope that it should be possible without re-configuring the setup entirely.

Please let me know if any other information is expected  from me.

Cheers!

- Edit: added the reverse proxy information to link from https://example.com/forum to my forum at 192.168.1.5/forum
- Edit 2: Removed the line with Alias for /forum and removed the '/' from the end of the reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: That reverse proxy part (for /http-bind) seems OK, can you elaborate in more detail what exactly did not work when you tried to use the same setup
 for /forum

Comment: I am sorry, like I said, I am not very well versed with Apache configuration so I am not sure what 'part' corresponds to reverse proxy for /http-bind specifically. I just tried duplicating the lines containing ProxyOreserveHost, ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, and changing the /http-bind to /forum and changing the link IP to the other server's IP that hosts my forum.

But that, evidently, did not work. I am even fine with forwarding the /forum requests to this server to the forum server without SSL. So, I guess change will be needed just in the <VirtualHost *:80> part. But I am not sure how.

Comment: Yes, you should copy/modify exactly those 3 lines, as you described. But can you explain what "did not work", how does it behave?

Comment: My main application is a jitsi-meet based video conferencing application. Right now https://example.com/roomname creates a virtual room called 'roomname' that multiple people can connect to and have a video conference. After I made the above changes, I made sure to restart Apache so that the configuration takes effect. But, even then, upon visiting https://example.com/forum, a conferencing room called forum was created where as I expected it to redirect me to my phpBB forum website that I had linked through reverseProxy. I appreciate your help. Please let me know if I am not being clear enough

Comment: I have even tried to restrict redirection (for a keyword, say, 'forum') by giving "ProxyPass /forum !" and such but the conference room is still being created. I have been tinkering with /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf. I hope that is the right file.

Comment: Does example.com/http-bind take you to the correct destination or also creates a conference room?

Comment: /http-bind takes me to the right page which says "It works! Now point your BOSH client to this URL to connect to Prosody." Just as an experiment, I changed the reverseProxy redirection of /http-bind to my forum URL and the redirection worked, but only text from the forum page was loaded (like pages look when javascript is disabled). The page loads properly when accessed through the local URL.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add the /forum part that you tested with. (first we need to fix proxypass, then we will fix styles)

Comment: I have added the reverse proxy configuration change that I have tested with.

Comment: 1) You already have `Alias /forum ...`, you might want to remove/comment that line

Comment: 2) If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa, so use `ProxyPass /forum http://192.168.1.5/forum`

Comment: I removed the Alias /forum as well as the trailing '/' from the ProxyPass lines. Edited to reflect the changes in main post too. The result is still the same: no redirection for http://example.com/forum.

Comment: I had just followed the convention that was there for /http-bind configuration and had left the trailing '/'. Alias bit was there from some stuff that I had been trying at that point of time. Is there a way that the video-conferencing installation may be affecting the redirection in anyway. I posted the same query on their mailing list but they said that it is a purely apache thing.

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum` directly above `RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.html`

Comment: Yes! That did it!! Now the linked forum page appears normally, with full script running. I cannot thank you enough for your patience. Can you please tell me what this specific line does? I really cannot thank you enough. :)

Comment: I will follow up with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to modify in your configuration:

-Remove `Alias /forum ...` line, it contradicts with what you are trying to achieve

-Add the ProxyPass directives for `/forum` URI:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /forum http://192.168.1.5/forum
ProxyPassReverse /forum http://192.168.1.5/forum
```

-Make sure that your Rewrite Rule (which will otherwise rewrite any request to `/index.html`) is not executed for `/forum`, by adding the condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.html
```

(`/http-bind` worked properly because it does not match regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have learned more about Apache in these past couple of days than I had in the past few years.